# How to use Pool.join() in Python multiprocessing module?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

Here is the code:

```
def function(index):
    print('start process '+str(index))
    time.sleep(1)
    print('end process '+str(index))
    return str(index)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=3)   
    for i in range(4):
        res = pool.apply_async(function,args=(i,)) 
        print(res.get())
    pool.close()
    print('done')
```

and the output:

```
start process 0
end process 0
0
start process 1
end process 1
1
start process 2
end process 2
2
start process 3
end process 3
3
done
```

In my opinion, if the I don't use the pool.join(), the code should only print 'done' and that's it, because the function of pool.join() is 'Wait for the worker processes to exit', but now without pool.join(), it get the same result.
I really don't understand.

Comment: can you please accept my answer.

Answer (score 4):

In your code, the method `get()` has the same effect as `join()`. It also waits for the process to finish because you want to *get* the result of it.

If you remove it from your code, you will see the 'done' being printed first:

```
done
start process 0
```

Answer (score 1):

`res.get` waits for the process to finish (how else would it get the return value?) which means that process 0 must finish before process 1 can start, and so on.

Remove `res.get` and you won't see the processes finish. Move `res.get` to a separate loop after the first one and you'll see they all start before any of them finish.

Also check out `Pool.map`.